# Getting snippets of text searched using FTS in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

We store one page of text in each sql record as a single NVARCHAR(MAX) column. This column is full text indexed by SQL 2008. We use FREETEXTTABLE to query the full text index to locate documents containing a given keyword or phrase. The end user wants to see a small text snippet for each hit returned by FREETEXTTABLE in grid form. Ideally, this snippet would be the text representing the searched for keyword/phrase along with the word immediately to the left and right of the hit so as to provide context within the larger document text. 
This is not an out of box feature.

How to do this in SQL Server ??

Thank you, 
Marcus